# Divorce without the process of divorce; is it possible to obtain a dissolution after 15 years?

Tags: divorce

Suppose a couple eloped to Idaho in 2008. They have not seen each other since 2009. Suppose that one lives in Washington and then other lives in Colorado.

Is there a way for such a couple to get a dissolution of marriage without going through the divorce process?

Suppose further that there is one common child involved. Suppose further  that he is 14 years old.

Suppose further that there was a no-contact order in effect  from 2009 to 2019 because of an assault by one member of the couple on the other, and the child.

Comment: "Is there a way for such a couple to get a dissolution of marriage without going through the divorce process?" No. There is not (other than as a result of the death of one of the parties terminating the marriage). There is no such thing as "common law divorce."

Comment: @ohwilleke Do you not credit user6726's [answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/88727/17500) or are you stating that the process of "dissolution" described in it answer is simply a form of divorce? Also, I believe that informal divorces are legal in some non-US jurisdictions.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I would see the terms "divorce" and "dissolution of marriage" as exact synonyms. The former is more colloquial but they mean exactly the same thing. So far as I know, only courts can grant divorces in all common law jurisdictions (with the possible exception of Indian tribe laws) and in all civil law jurisdictions. Non-court divorces are allowed in Islamic law. There may be other outlier cases of which I am not aware (e.g. I don't know how divorce works, e.g., in China, or in canon law, or under Jewish law, or for Indian Hindus). But these are not annulment facts.

Comment: @ohwilleke My understanding is that informal divorces were permitted under traditional Jewish law. I am not sure if this is still true in the modern State of Israel. In any case that will not be relevant to a person living in the US.

Comment: @ohwillek as this question is now open again, you could post an answer based on your comment if you wished to.

Answer (score 2):

The party who lives in Washington can petition dissolution under [this chapter](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=26.09&full=true). It does not matter where they were married or lived, what just matters that the party filing the petition lives in Washington. Having a child is not a bar to dissolution. That much is extremely simple. If the two parties cannot agree to the dissolution and to the child-custody plan, lawyers would be involved to reach an agreement.

It is worth noting that for 50 years, divorce has been replaced in Washington with dissolution. It is also worth noting that there is an alternative path which may be more efficiency, namely legal separation. The primary downside of a separation is that it is a bar to re-marriage (you are still married). But, under RCW 26.09.150

> No earlier than six months after entry of a decree of legal
> separation, on motion of either party, the court shall convert the
> decree of legal separation to a decree of dissolution of marriage or
> domestic partnership.

This is a matter of right that cannot be objected to.